# SequelizeConnectionError: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a NodeJS aplication and I am using Sequelize to connnect to Postgres data base; in my developer versión all work fine, but in my production version after do some calls from two machine get the following error `SequelizeConnectionError:  FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections.` In many question say that the solution is increase the max_connections in my database; actually have this parameter in 100 but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

the problem would be in the sequelize configuration, maybe I have close the connection manually?

here is my config.json file

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "pys-form",
    "password": "pys-form",
    "database": "PYS-FORM-COL",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "pys-form",
    "password": "pys-form",
    "database": "PYS-FORM-COL",
    "host": "190.60.234.132",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

index.js file

```
var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production";
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably open connection but not closing it. The open connection stays idle and just waste the slots.

If you use pgAdmin you can go to Tools -> Server Status menu and see those pending connections.

You can also try try this to get [activity statistics](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Comment: Hi @Adam thanks for the answer, I'm suspect the same that the connection are not closed but the database was in ubuntu server without GUI how can check that in psql?

Comment: I've updated my answer, so you can check connections with simply SQL.